# Error while posting to facebook friends wall using WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post to my Friends wall using WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder using facebook Android sdk.

Here is my code :

```
               Bundle params = new Bundle();

                params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
                params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
                params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
                params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
                params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");


            params.putString("to", friend_uid);

                WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, mCurrentSession, params))
                        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                // and the post Id.
                                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                if (postId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                                        "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, 
                                        "Publish cancelled", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                // User clicked the "x" button
                                Toast.makeText(activity, 
                                    "Publish cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // Generic, ex: network error
                                Toast.makeText(activity, 
                                    "Error posting story", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }



                    }).build();
                feedDialog.show();
```

when I remove a line below from my above code,I can successfully post on my timeline.

```
 params.putString("to", friend_uid);
```

But when I keep this line to post to my friends timeline I am getting the dialog with message

```
  "Cannot Post to User's Wall Error" with  Ok Button
```

[image]

I am sure I have got the required permissions.I have also printed in my Log

Permissions that I have for my session are below

```
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[photo_upload, publish_stream, video_upload, installed, publish_checkins, publish_actions, share_item, user_friends, email, user_photos, public_profile, status_update, create_note, basic_info]}, appId:xxxxx402xxxx}
```

I have searched a lot in SO and in Google,but didnt find any solution. 
Did I need to give any other settings for my app? 
Please Suggest me in solving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish in your friends timeline, you should add this code into your Bundle before the "to" parameter:     `params.putString("from",fbid_sender);//where fbid_sender is the facebook id of the user is making the post`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3)

> to --> The ID of the profile that this story will be published to. If this
>   is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from. The **ID must be a
>   friend who also uses your app**

Secondly, from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3)

> Note
>
> If a person has the "Who can post on your timeline?" **setting set to
>   "Only me" and another person tries to make a post using the Feed
>   dialog, it will display a "Cannot post" error.**

Finally, from the [upgrade](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x) docs

> Feed Dialog - Instead of using the Feed Dialog directly (via
>   WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder in v3.x), you should now use ShareDialog,
>   which will use the native Share Dialog in the Facebook app if
>   installed, and fall back to a webview. If you explicitly want to show
>   only the Feed Dialog, you can use ShareDialog.show(content,
>   ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);